# library not found for -lrt with QtCreator [mac os]

Tags: c, macos, compiler-construction, qt4, compilation

i'm getting some troubles with QT it builds with option "-lrt"

i'm using mac os 10.6 with QT creator 1.2.1, heeeeeeelp !

this is the full build command :

> g++ -headerpad_max_install_names -o
>   AMiningCoreTest main.o tokenizer.o
>   DictionnaryToolBox.o mysql.o btree.o
>   BTreeDataTable.o tcaccess.o
>   -L/Library/Frameworks -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient -L/usr/local/lib/ -ltokyocabinet -lz -lbz2 -lrt -lpthread -lm -lc

and it ends with

> ld: library not found for -lrt
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why does the program need librt?

I know that some platforms (Solaris comes to mind) require librt for some functions which might exist in other libraries in your OS.  (sem_init() et al. are like this)

You might try to link without -lrt and see if it works.

Comment: Yes i've modified the build command to disable the -lrt library and it works :)

thank you ^^

Answer (score 16):

The linker cannot find librt which is probably the Posix real time extensions library. I don't think this is available on OSX. Googling gives this from [Apple developer lists](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905193454/http://lists.apple.com/archives/unix-porting/2008/Oct/msg00001.html)

Question from list

> I'm trying to build a simulator developed in my university (on Linux)
>   and I get error by the linker that seems unable to find librt.a - in
>   the code is used for clock_gettime() and I would like to know if
>   there's a port of such library, or some other similar function that
>   allows me to compile even on Mac OS X.
>
> Answer
>   librt.a is the System V name of the library containing the POSIX
>   Advanced Realtime [RT} Option functions. The specific function you are
>   asking about is part of the [TMR] option. If Mac OS X supported it, it
>   would be in libSystem.B,dylib, not librt.a. The function in question
>   is not supported by Mac OS X.
>
> Your code should check to see whether optional to implement things
>   above and beyond the UNIX standard are implemented in the target OS,
>   and if they aren't, use a different interface.

Comment: Funnily enough, POSIX requires `-lrt` to work. Seems Apple solved this by ignoring that flag when the compiler is invoked with the POSIX standard `c99` command. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/c99.html#tag_20_11_13_01