# Installing GPUOCELOT under OSX Lion 10.7

Tags: boost, cuda, emulation, gpu

I'm new to stackoverflow. My question ia about gpuocelet. Is there anybody using it? Does it work on unix (I'm using a macbook air with os x 10.7) OS? I tried in many way to install it but without success. I installed correctly all the packages required from macports following these instructions http://code.google.com/p/gpuocelot/downloads/detail?name=Ocelot_Installation_manual2.pdf 
In particular I installed boost 1.50 via macports but the error I get running the ./configure in gpuocelot folder is :

`MacBook-Air-di-Manfredo:downloads manfredo$ cd ocelot-2.0.969/

    MacBook-Air-di-Manfredo:ocelot-2.0.969 manfredo$ ./configure

    checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c

    checking whether build environment is sane... yes

    checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d

    checking for gawk... no

    checking for mawk... no

    checking for nawk... no

    checking for awk... awk

    checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes

    checking for style of include used by make... GNU

    checking for gcc... gcc

    checking whether the C compiler works... yes

    checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out

    checking for suffix of executables...

    checking whether we are cross compiling... no

    checking for suffix of object files... o

    checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes

    checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes

    checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed

    checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3

    checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E

    checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep

    checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E

    checking for ANSI C header files... yes

    checking for sys/types.h... yes

    checking for sys/stat.h... yes

    checking for stdlib.h... yes

    checking for string.h... yes

    checking for memory.h... yes

    checking for strings.h... yes

    checking for inttypes.h... yes

    checking for stdint.h... yes

    checking for unistd.h... yes

    checking minix/config.h usability... no

    checking minix/config.h presence... no

    checking for minix/config.h... no

    checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes

    checking for main in -lboost_system-mt... no

    configure: error: "libboost_system required"

    MacBook-Air-di-Manfredo:ocelot-2.0.969 manfredo$`

my PATH is

> ```
>         PATH=/Users/manfredo/downloads/boost_1_42_0/stage/lib:/Users/manfredo/downloads/boost_1_42_0/libs:/Users/manfredo/downloads/boost_1_42_0/libs:/Users/manfredo/downloads/boost_1_42_0/boost/system:/Users/manfredo/downloads/boost_1_42_0/boost:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/lib:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
> ```

Every help is welcome, Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Boost in /Users/manfredo/downloads/boost_1_42_0/stage/lib or in macports - and this should not be in your path but in INCLUDE and LIB environment variables

Comment: Thank you Mark, your answer has been useful. I deleted the download folder of boost and used only the macports version. I added the following lines in teh terminal
    MacBook-Air-di-Manfredo:~ manfredo$ CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/local/include/boost
    MacBook-Air-di-Manfredo:~ manfredo$ export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
    MacBook-Air-di-Manfredo:~ manfredo$ LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib
    MacBook-Air-di-Manfredo:~ manfredo$ export LIBRARY_PATH
Now the libboost is found but it still gives me an error:

checking for clock_gettime in -lrt... no
configure: error: "librt required"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have another tried to install version of Boost installed un your home directory as you have put it on your path, also Boost does not go on the path but headers should be in the INCLUDE environment variable and libraries in a lib variable.

For macports these are /opt/local/include and /opt/local/lib respectively.

e.g. for Cmake from the [variables that control the build](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#section_VariablesthatControltheBuild)

```
CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR=/opt/local/include
CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH_FLAG=/opt/local/lib
```

Comment: I think that right now the boost libraries are correctly linked. The report is :
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking for main in -lboost_system-mt... yes
checking for main in -lboost_filesystem-mt... yes
checking for main in -lboost_wserialization-mt... yes
checking for main in -lboost_serialization-mt... yes
checking for main in -lboost_thread-mt... yes
checking for glewInit in -lGLEW... yes
checking for clock_gettime in -lrt... no
configure: error: "librt required"

I wasn't able to find anything useful about this -librt library, what do you think about? Thx

Comment: librt is the Posix real time library but not on OSX where all its functions are in the main C library so you need to edit the makefile to remove it. See my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505402/library-not-found-for-lrt-with-qtcreator-mac-os

Comment: This post ( https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/gpuocelot/0mhpB2B_xxw ) seems to me significant for understanding the procedure to install gpuocelot on mac osx, in particular the last line:
"I am getting a Linux box soon, so I am giving up."
Probably is the best thing to do...