# Error when compiling with -lrt using g++ on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, g++, posix

When compiling a file with `g++ -o filename source.cpp -lrt` on OSX  I'm getting the following output:

```
ld: library not found for -lrt
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The file is an example of POSIX shared memory objects which needs to be linked with `-lrt` to work. It linked fine in Linux, but when I try to compile it in OSX I get that "*library not found*" error.

When linked without the `-lrt` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1506342/4683496) it compiles, but when executed, the `shm_open()` function returns with this error: `shm_open: Invalid argument`.
When linked on Linux with `-lrt` it works fine, but without `-lrt` it produces the same error "*Invalid Argument*".

The `-lrt` is also specified as needed in [the Linux man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html) of `shm_open()`. But curiously it's never mentioned in the `man shm_open` of the terminal in OSX.

If the case is that the library is not available in Mac OSX (as also suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1506031/4683496)) then what else can I use instead of `shm_open()` to create/open POSIX shared memory objects so that my code can be compiled both in OSX and Linux. Or is there something I'm missing here to get this to work?

---

Here's the important bit of the src in case it helps:

```cpp
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>        /* For mode constants */
#include <fcntl.h>           /* For O_* constants */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
   int shmfd = shm_open("evaluator", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_TRUNC, 0660);

   if (shmfd < 0) {
      perror("shm_open");
      exit(1);
   }

   if (ftruncate(shmfd, sizeof(int) * 10) < 0) {
      perror("ftruncate");
      exit(1);
   }

   close(shmfd);
   exit(0);
}
```

Comment: @Roddy I just added how the answers in the question marked as duplicate of this one don't fully address my question. How should we proceed with this? What is the "Etiquette" to follow here on StackOverflow? Should the question be reopened, or did I truly miss something in the other question that solves my question? -Thanks in advance

Comment: The right etiquette in your case would be to ask another question. "Why does shm_open return Invalid argument". Your initial question about -Lrt has been answered, and it's moved you on to what is actually an unrelated problem!