# Issue when linking with `-lrt` on Mac OSX

Tags: c, macos, gcc, linker, macos-high-sierra

On my Mac OSX 10.13, I always use the following makefile to compile C codes:

```
TARGET = run
LIBS = -O2 -lm -lrt
CC = gcc

.PHONY: default all clean

all: $(TARGET)

OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard *.c))
HEADERS = $(wildcard *.h)

%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PRECIOUS: $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $@

clean:
    -rm -f *.o
    -rm -f $(TARGET)
```

Note that I use `-lrt` on purpose because I use `#include <aio.h>` for some of my codes. Because of that, I keep getting this error:

```
ld: library not found for -lrt
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [run] Error 1
```

This error does **not** show up when running on Linux systems. How do I fix that to be runnable on Mac OSX?

Comment: Just to test, does the program link successfully if you drop `-lrt` from `LIBS`?  (Incidentally, `-O2` belongs in CFLAGS, not LIBS; it isn't doing you hardly any good where you have it.)

Comment: @zwol No it does not! Removing `-O2` does not link it. And thanks for letting me know that `-O2` belongs to CFLAGS

Comment: Is the `librt.so` file in the standard paths of libs like `/usr/lib`? Perhaps you should also pass the `-L` option with the path where to find `librt.so`.

Comment: @Pablo I cannot find `librt.so` in `/usr/lib` or even `/usr/include`!!

Comment: `librt.so` should be included in your toolchain when you installed your compiler. I don't use mac, so I don't know which package you should install. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1506031/1480131

Comment: Based on  a quick [google search](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&client=firefox-b&ei=KI2oWq-LIsKNsgGg_raoCg&q=librt.so+mac&oq=librt.so+mac&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160k1.142216.142695.0.143183.4.4.0.0.0.0.149.419.0j3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.3.417...0i30k1j0i22i30k1.0.MzCO07vN88Y) I've found many github bug reports with the same problem. Apparently for Darwin you don't need `-lrt` at all.

Comment: @Pablo Thank you very much for your effort. I truly appreciate it. Even if removing `-lrt`, I still have this issue. Hopefully, someone has a solution

Comment: You don't need `-lm` on Macs either, even though you do on Linux.  Macs put more of the code in the central library and rely on fewer auxilliary libraries.  If you're really worried, you can create a `librt.a` in the current directory and it will be linked.  It needn't hold anything much (but it does need an object file in it).  I created a source file `unlinked.c` containing `extern void I_wont_link_this_function_if_I_can_help_it(void);
void I_wont_link_this_function_if_I_can_help_it(void)
{
}`; compiled it; and ran `ar rv librt.a unlinked.o`.  I could then link programs with `-L. -lrt`.

Comment: You ought to be getting a different error message or messages with `-lrt` removed from `LIBS`.  Please show us those error messages.  (I have a bad feeling that the ultimate answer is going to be "OSX doesn't implement the interfaces you are trying to use...")