# What is the C library "rt"?

Tags: c, macos, gcc, cmake, opencl

I was trying to run a simple OpenCL test program for a course assignment. But I got an error when running `make`.

The error is:

> `ld: library not found for -lrt`

I checked the `Makefile`, and found the related line was:

```
cl-demo: cl-demo.c cl-helper.c
gcc $(CL_CFLAGS) $(CL_LDFLAGS) -std=gnu99 -o$@ $^ -lrt -lOpenCL -v
```

While my fellow classmates using Ubuntu 16.04 managed to run this test program just fine, I am using macOS High Sierra. The TAs nor the professor cannot figure it out (unfortunately, they only have experience of OpenCL on Ubuntu).

It feels like that the missing library `rt` seems be a library from some common package, but I don't know which package it comes from. Is it exclusive to Ubuntu or Linux? Does anybody knows where it comes from? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try just removing `-lrt`? It is part of the standard C library, other platforms may have those functions somewhere linked by defaut.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505402/library-not-found-for-lrt-with-qtcreator-mac-os might help

Comment: Note that even on Ubuntu 16.04, it'd work with `-lrt` if you're using glibc because it's [no longer a separate library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32649327/1275169). Since you are MacOS, you can just remove it and compile - if it compiles then you don't need it at all!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that!

Comment: I just found that I have a new issue regarding to the `-lOpenCL` option... Which also says not found...